# How to match all characters from a sequence excluding specific characters?

Tags: regex

How to delete all the control characters but exclude the newline (`U+2028`) character?

```
preg_replace('/[\p{Cc}]/', '', $response);
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
/(?!\x{2028})\p{Cc}/u
```

You also need to enable [UTF8 mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to match unicode.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\p{Cc}(?!\x{2028})`?

Comment: @sp00m: That would match any control character not *followed* by a newline character.

Comment: +1 this is probably easier to understand than the double negation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use double negation

```
preg_replace('/[^\P{Cc}\x{2028}]/u', '', $response);
```

`\P{Cc}` is the negation of `\p{Cc}`

`[^...]` is negated character class

So you match everything that is not not a Control character and that is not `\x{2028}`. This way you can exclude certain characters from predefined character classes.

Comment: Didn't think about `\P`, although it is mentioned in the PHP docs the OP linked to. +1